# Can not get data back in first activity from map activity in android using kotlin

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I am starting a map activity and sending back coordinates from the map using `startActivityForRsult()` but I am not receiving any data in the previous activity.

I am using following code:

**For starting activity**

```
startActivityForResult(Intent(this@ActivityCompanyTimings, ActivityPickLocation::class.java), 120)
```

**onActivityResult()**

```
 override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    if (requestCode == 120 && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        Toast.makeText(this, intent.getStringExtra("result"), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
    }
}
```

**following code for sending data back from map activity:**

```
 val returnIntent = Intent()
 returnIntent.putExtra("result", "${marker.position.latitude}, ${marker.position.longitude}")
 setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, returnIntent)
 finish()
```

Toast shows blank.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your have to use `data.getStringExtra("result")`, instead of `intent.getStringExtra("result")` in your `onActivityResult()`.

```
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    if (requestCode == 120 && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        Toast.makeText(this, data?.getStringExtra("result"), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
    }
}
```

Comment: To add to this: Calling intent will get you the `Intent` that was used to start the current `Activity`